# Python: nlst error. Empty directory

Tags: python, ftplib

I have a code which downloads zip files from a ftp server. When I try to catch files on an empty directory, the code fails.
It works fine when I have files in the directory.

These errors appears when the directory is empty.

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ftplib.py", line 459, in nlst
    self.retrlines(cmd, files.append)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ftplib.py", line 421, in retrlines
    return self.voidresp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ftplib.py", line 221, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ftplib.py", line 216, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 550 No files found.
```

I tried to fix this error with the next code, but it doesn't work. It keeps happening.
If somebody can help me with a solution, I'd appreciate it

## CODE

```
try:
    fileList = s.nlst()
except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
    if str(resp) == '550 No files found':
        print 'Directory is empty.'
else:
    raise
```

which still results in

```
File "/root/folder/ftp.py", line 151, in download fileList = s.nlst() 
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ftplib.py", line 459, in nlst self.retrlines(cmd, files.append) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ftplib.py", line 421, in retrlines return self.voidresp() 
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ftplib.py", line 221, in voidresp resp = self.getresp() 
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ftplib.py", line 216, in getresp raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 550 No files found.
```

Comment: The fix looks reasonable (other than that the indentation here is wrong); can you show the *full* traceback when the error happens using your updated code?

Comment: the indentation was placed by stackoverflow. Nothing to do, or wouldn't let me post.

Comment: File "/root/folder/ftp.py", line 151, in download
    fileList = s.nlst()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ftplib.py", line 459, in nlst
    self.retrlines(cmd, files.append)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ftplib.py", line 421, in retrlines
    return self.voidresp()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ftplib.py", line 221, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ftplib.py", line 216, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 550 No files found.

Comment: Have you tried with normal ftp on the command line? It may simply be an permission problem, that is, you don't have access to view that directory (in which case, the error message is somewhat deceiving).

Comment: I have access, it is not a permission problem :/

Comment: have a similar problem, looks like the behaviour is differently pn different ftp server implementations. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2383827 for example.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is dead but I found this because I had the same problem. Here is the workaround I used:

```
def handle_folders(item):

    global fldrs
    temp = item.split()
    if item.startswith('d') and temp[4] != "512":
        fldrs.append(myFldr + item[54:] + "/")

ftp.cwd(myFldr)
ftp.retrlines('LIST', handle_folders)
setupDir = fldrs
```

where myFldr is the path and you filter out anything that isnt a folder and any empty ones. Elsewhere in my code I iterate through setupDir and use ftp.nlst() to get a list of files, though you could also use retrlines to get that list.